# check if materialized view is populated

Tags: postgresql

Using postgres 9.5.2 (python client)

Is there any way to check if a materialized view is populated using a query? One that does not raise a warning the view is not populated?

Comment: `select count(*) from mv` ??

Comment: try it, it raises the following error:
`ERROR: materialized view "<mv_name>" has not been populated Hint: Use the REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW command.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The quick answer:

```
SELECT relispopulated FROM pg_class WHERE relname = '<the table name>';
```

You can find more details about the `pg_class` table [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html). According to that, the field `relispopulated` should be true for everything but some materialized views, and I infer from that and from the name of the field, that it will give you what you want.

Comment: Just a heads-up: the catalog schema is fairly stable, but they do reserve the right to change it between versions. Make sure to include a test on this, and run it whenever you want to do a postgres upgrade.