# Remove parenthesis in postgresql loop

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

Can someone help me understand why I get a parenthesis around the schemaname `nspname`? And/or, a way to remove it, so the loop will work?

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    views_ CURSOR FOR
        SELECT nspname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace
        WHERE nspname LIKE '%scemanames%';
BEGIN
    FOR nspname IN views_ LOOP
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO forkert_ejendom_roert SELECT * FROM ' || nspname || '.viewname';
        -- Do something with nbRow
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

The output i get is:

> ```
> ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
> LINE 1: ...m_roert SELECT * FROM ('schemanames).bbr_punk...
>                                      ^
> QUERY: INSERT INTO forkert_ejendom_roert SELECT * FROM (name of the schema).viewname 
> CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at EXECUTE 
>
> ********** Error **********
> ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" SQL state: 42601 
> Context: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at EXECUTE
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop variable is a record (actually containing a single column), try:

```
    FOR rec IN views_ LOOP
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO forkert_ejendom_roert SELECT * FROM ' || rec.nspname || '.viewname';
```

Comment: Some of the views are not populated, which is causing an error. Is there a good way to deal with this?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. You can check whether a view is populated (see [check if materialized view is populated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40959486/1995738)), or automatically refresh all views, or place `execute` in an exception block.

Comment: I solved it by adding an exception, that raises a notice whenever an empty table is encountered. Error number: 55000, object_not_in_prerequisite_state. Thanks again!